# Problem with saving as pdf - not right location

Tags: pdf, save-as

I have a problem too, when i am saving it saves where mainc excel file is located.
please help ^^

```
Sub Save PDF()

Dim filePath As String
Dim filename As String
filePath = "C:\Users\lasha\Documents\"
filename = Sheets("Form").Range("D2")
Sheets("Form").Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=filename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with myself ^^ filename:=filePath & filename   that was chaneged and it works.

```
Sub Save PDF
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim filename As String
    filePath = "C:\Users\lasha\Documents\"
    filename = Sheets("Form").Range("D2")
    Sheets("Form").Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=filePath & filename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
            True
    End Sub
```